# Cannot log into Windows 10

Tags: windows, login

Sorry if this isn't the right place to ask this question, but I really need some help fast and I don't know where else to go.

I recently started working for a building contractors, and seeing as I had some IT experience I was asked to check all the PCs in the building.

I got to one PC that seemed to be unused and checked it out.  On logging in Windows told me that the password for this machine needed to be changed.  The account is just called "User" and the previous password was (apparently) nothing at all, just blank.  As far as I can tell this account User has no details associated with it, no email address associated with it.

So I changed the password to something really simple.

...and this has caused me lots of problems.

A few days later I was informed that the PC is important and gets used, and that I shouldn't have changed the password.  I tried to tell them that Windows was specifically asking for a new password but they didn't understand and continued to blame me for changing the password.

They were then able to get onto the PC with this new password.

A week later and someone goes to use the PC again, and the password I put into it no longer works.  As far as I can tell someone has changed the password again, however everyone I have spoken to about this has denied changing the password.  The password issue is still seen as my fault, they don't understand the situation, they don't want to understand the situation, they just want it fixed.

I just need to be able to log onto the machine, I doubt they would notice the difference from one user account to the other, they just need to be able to see past the log in screen to be convinced that the machine is no longer "broken".

The current situation I have is when trying to log into this Windows 10 machine, it prompts me for a password to the account User, and regardless of whatever I try as a password I get the wait animation for about 30+ seconds.  It then tells me the password was incorrect, and allows me to try again.  There is no "forgotten password"/"password recovery" link at all.

Because I initially changed the password, everything that has followed since has been blamed on me, and I am now seen as "breaking" one of their PCs because it can no longer be used.  There is now a lot of pressure on me to "get it working again" before tomorrow.
Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Use a password recovery tool. Then set the password on the user account to never expire. Then enable the option "User cannot change password". - https://www.top-password.com/knowledge/reset-windows-10-password.html - https://www.lifewire.com/free-windows-password-recovery-tools-2626179

Answer (score 1):

> On logging in Windows told me that the password for this machine
> needed to be changed.

Do you mean the machine link to the domain is broke ? Rejoin the machine to the domain.

or use netdom to reset the computer account.

netdom.exe resetpwd /s:**server** /ud:**user** /pd:*

**server** = a domain controller.

**user** = domain admin account.

Comment: How do I do any of this if I cannot log onto the computer?  Is it possible to bring up the command prompt from the log in screen?

Comment: @Jimmery You need to use a local account, if you have none, you will need to use a boot cd, and remove any password from a local user.